# Context menu items missing after uninstalling ReSharper from VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I uninstalled the ReSharper demo after a test run, and now a number of my context menu items in the code editor are missing.  The one that I immediately noticed was gone was the C# refactoring menu, but the list is significantly shorter overall so I know it's not the only one that isn't there.

I tried `Tools - Import and Export Settings - Reset all settings` and `Tools - Customize - Commands - Context Menu - Editor Context Menu - Reset All`, but neither restored the missing items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently one of the reset options I'd tried required a restart of Visual Studio to be effective; but failed to indicate the fact.